# How to make errors class types strict in Typescript

Tags: typescript, error-handling, typescript-generics

I'm using TypeScript for a project and I'm doing error handling, but I observed some behavior of TS that makes my system less strict about error types :

```
class A extends Error {}
class B extends Error {}
// I can do this
const err: A = new B();
```

I would prefer it throwing an error because those are not the same class, but it works fine and thus loosen my error types restrictions. Do anyone know how could I make it impossible to define an A object with a B constructor ?

For your information I'd like to make this possible because I use functional error handling library and I define in a method's definition the errors it could throw, but it causes issues when the error types are not strict enough

I think that it may be because A and B have the same definition regarding their properties even though they're different classes, I've tried setting different properties in them but didn't succeed.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that assignment because TypeScript's type system is *structural* (based on the shapes of types), not nominal (based on the names/identities of types). `A` and `B` both create instances with the same set of properties, so they're assignment-compatible.

You can solve this with "branding" — giving each of your `Error` subclasses a unique property value:

```typescript
class A extends Error {
    readonly type = "A";
}
class B extends Error {
    readonly type = "B";
}

// Error here as desired
const err: A = new B();
//    ^Type 'B' is not assignable to type 'A'.
//      Types of property 'type' are incompatible.
//        Type '"B"' is not assignable to type '"A"'. (2322)
```

[Playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECC0FMAeAXBA7AJjAogJzwHs9oBvAKGiujwTE0PRAE9oVmAHBaAXmgCJY-ANzkAvuVCQYAIUSoM2aPiIkK1GnQZNW7LrwEyR48uQD0Z5QWLQAFglrRI0TAggBLWpkmMIKRAQAXHAG6AgA7tAyABQAlKIWGgB6ACqc3ADkMhnQ7jDohP7S7gDm6GAARiDcKIRs6dAZsBkAdOaWGtBpXDCEAGbQHERceOyNegg5YI7u6MCEALYcYCjuVQhtiZ1U3Zn8Rjl50AVFUKXl62x1E42C-K3Q0QBMAMxPT7HkQA)

---

In a comment you've asked:

> Do you think it's possible to do error inheritance with this approach ? Because it would mean that the child has to override a parent's property but it would mean that I couldn't specify just the parent if I don't need a child level precision.

Yes, you can do that by using different marker properties instead of a single `type` property:

```typescript
class A extends Error {
    readonly __A__ = "A";
}
class B extends Error {
    readonly __B__ = "B";
}
class C extends B { // <== `C` subclasses `B`
    readonly __C__ = "C";
}

// Works (of course)
const errorA: A = new A();
const errorB: B = new B();
const errorC: C = new C();

// Using parent type works with subclass
const errorB2: B = new C();

// (As desired) Using subclass type with parent class doesn't work 
const errorC2: C = new B();
//    ^Property '__C__' is missing in type 'B' but required in type 'C'. (2741)
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECC0FMAeAXBA7AJjAogJzwHs9oBvAKGiujwTE0PRAE9oB9N2D6AXmgCJY-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)

Comment: Thank you, I'll do that. Do you think it's possible to do error inheritance with this approach ? Because it would mean that the child has to override a parent's property but it would mean that I couldn't specify just the parent if I don't need a child level precision

Comment: @ezrae - Yes, you can use a separate property per class rather than using a single `type` property, I've added an example.